# How to recess a recessed socket even deeper into drywall?

Tags: electrical, uk

I have a standard UK double socket recessed into 15mm drywall. Currently the frame protrudes by approximately 5mm from the wall, and the switches protrude from the frame by a further 5mm.

I wish for the socket to be completely flush with the wall, such that you could run your hand over it and barely know it's there.

[image: Standard Recessed United Kingdom Double Face Plate Socket]

Does anyone know of an alternative faceplate for a UK style double socket which is completely flush with the wall (a bit like the TruFig US one below)?

Alternatively, a good way of recessing my current socket 10mm into 15mm drywall?

This socket will be behind a very, very thin and closely mounted wall mount TV so I don't mind how it looks, although ideally I don't want to completely remove the socket.

[image: TruFig socket]

Comment: Just curious - do you need those extra 10mm to get the TV mounted and plugged in?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the box without the cover plate?

Comment: @FreeMan Yeah the extra 10mm actually do make a difference for this TV and room layout.

Comment: @JACK It's very, very similar to this one (I think it might even be identical): https://www.amazon.co.uk/Extra-Deep-Lining-Back-Pattress-Plastic/dp/B017XLJH5W

Comment: It seems like you'd be able to score around the cover plate about 10mm deep, remove the material and reinstall the box and cover plate further back into the wall.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=uk+recessed+socket&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: if you don't care how it looks, why not remove the faceplate?